# Xml write twice the same thing

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing

i'm looking to solve this problem. 
When i try to write into the xml file , it writes twice the same thing.

It's the code:

```
    def writeIntoXml(fileName, tagElement, textElement):
    tree = ET.ElementTree(file = fileName)
    root = tree.getroot()
    newElement = ET.SubElement(root, tagElement)
    newElement.text =textElement;
    newElement.tail ="\n"
    root.append(newElement)
    tree.write(fileName, encoding='utf-8')
```

If i have this xml file, with this tags, if i write a new tag( es "Question-3" Example3 "/Question-3") i get a problem

XmlFile before being written:

```
<Questions>
    <Question-1>Example1</Question-1>
    <Question-2>Example2</Question-2>
</Questions>
```

XmlFile after being written:

```
<Questions>
    <Question-1>Example1</Question-1>
    <Question-2>Example2</Question-2>
    <Question-3>Example3</Question-3>
    <Question-3>Example3</Question-3>
</Questions>
```

Sorry for grammatical errors

Comment: You have a correct answer below, so, please, mark it as approved. It will help other users do not pay attention at your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [ET.SubElement()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.SubElement) appends the element automatically. You are adding the element twice, first in `SubElement()`, next in `append()`.

You should use either just

```
newElement = ET.SubElement(root, tagElement)
newElement.text = textElement;
newElement.tail = "\n"
```

or

```
newElement = ET.Element(tagElement)
newElement.text = textElement;
newElement.tail = "\n"
root.append(newElement)
```

Comment: Damn, thank you ^^ i fix it . It was so easy, happens